# Deriving of the Jacobi bracket and the chain rule

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

[image]

This is from a passage that derives the Jacobi bracket from first principles. I cannot understand how the first equality works. It seems to use the chain rule and I agree with the second term but the first one I cannot see it works. Is there is a derivative of something that equals the identity map?

$\mathbb{X}$ is a vector field. $\mathbb{X}_s=\Psi_s \mathbb{X}$. $\Psi_s$ is the flow of the vector field $\mathbb{Y}$.

Comment: You need to explain some of this notation. Is $\mathbb{X}$ a vector field? $\Psi_s$, the flow of another vector field, perhaps $\mathbb{Y}$?

Comment: I have edited my question to include this information now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually just the total derivative you probably learned in multivariable calculus. Remember this goes like so: if $F=F(x(t),t)$ then $dF/dt=\partial F/\partial t+\partial F/\partial x dx/dt.$ It's the same computation here.